# AEM custom widget:: dynamically adding fieldLabel and fieldDescription

Tags: extjs, aem

I have created a custom widget. Below given is the code snippet

```
this.word = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
  fieldLabel: "Word",
  fieldDescription: "Please enter a word in the format: Word",
  allowBlank: false,
  autoWidth: false,
 // regex: /^[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$/,
 // regexText: 'Enter only alphabets here.First character has to be an alphabet in uppercase.',
  listeners: {
    change: {
      scope: this,
      fn: this.updateHidden
    }
  }
});
```

The widget works fine. And I have another requirements which is similar to this in terms of functionality. The only thing different are the values of fieldLabel and fieldDescription. I don't think creating another widget for this would be a good idea. Is there any way I can make these two dynamic.

FYI, I am using AEM 6.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use a listener and change the value on the fly. I tried it with the [added](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Ext.form.TextField#CQ.Ext.form.TextField-added) event and it seems to work.

```
this.word = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
 fieldLabel: "Word",
 fieldDescription: "Please enter a word in the format: Word",
 allowBlank: false,
 autoWidth: false,
 // regex: /^[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$/,
 // regexText: 'Enter only alphabets here.First character has to be an alphabet in uppercase.',
 listeners: {
   change: {
     scope: this,
     fn: this.updateHidden
   },
   added: function(textfield,ownerct,index){
    if(//some condition here){
      textfield.fieldLabel = "new field label",
      textfield.fieldDescription = "new field description"
     } 
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: Hey Sharath, thanks for your response. I may be dumb in asking this. But if the 'added:function..' goes inside the JS and the fieldLabel value ("new field label") is being set in the JS itself,  I am not sure how it is making the fieldLabel and fieldDescription dynamic. Again, I may be sounding stupid or naive but then ExtJs is just not my forte. And would appreciate if you could do a little hand handling here. Thanks.

Comment: when would you want to change the field label and description ? are the values predetermined ?

Comment: I was thinking of defining the fieldLabel and fieldDescription as the properties of the component. i.e. assigning these two properties to the cq:Component. What do you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want use same widget for different components, and for each component must be unique field (for you - fieldLabel and fieldDescription),

try this:

```
var label = this.fieldLabel;
var description = this.fieldDescription;

this.word = new CQ.Ext.form.TextField({
    fieldLabel: (label || label == '') ? label : "Word",
    fieldDescription: (description || description == '') ? description : "Please enter a word in the format: Word",
    allowBlank: false,
    autoWidth: false,
    // regex: /^[A-Z][a-zA-Z\s]+$/,
    // regexText: 'Enter only alphabets here.First character has to be an alphabet in uppercase.',
    listeners: {
        change: {
            scope: this,
            fn: this.updateHidden
        }
    }
});
```

"this.fieldLabel" - get new value 'fieldLabel' from Component's Dialog where you use widget:

```
...
fieldLabel="New Value fieldLabel For Custom Widget"
xtype="yourCustomWidget"/>
...
```